# new to java - understanding newInstance() when creating a fragment

Tags: java, android

in creating a new fragment, the constructor of this class has this `newInstance` which I am not sure what it does, perhaps you can explain to me what it is doing ?

```java
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
private int mIndex = 0;

public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {

DetailsFragment df = new DetailsFragment();
// Supply index input as an argument.
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("index", index);
df.setArguments(args);
return df;
}

public static DetailsFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
int index = bundle.getInt("index", 0);
return newInstance(index);
}
```

From my limited knowledge of Java, i think it is creating a new object of this class.. but if that is the case,then why not just write DetailsFragment df = new DetailsFragment() in the main ? It seems like it is doing the something.

Answer (score 3):

The `newInstance` function is a convenience function that is customary to use in Android. The point of the function is to make sure you always call `setArguments` when creating the fragment, because the fragment requires those arguments. You are right that you are not **required** to do things this way. It is just a customary pattern.

You cannot just create a constructor with arguments because Android needs to be able to instantiate those fragments and it wouldn't be able to supply those parameters.

Comment: Your last paragraph is important, it's the main reason we see newInstance() being used - we want to create an instance with parameters but it would be a bad idea to use anything other than the default constructor, because the Android system will recreate using the default constructor.

Comment: thats a good point, newInstance or constructor should only be used to create bundle for setArguments. But I dont see why constructor should not be used for that instead of newInstance.

Comment: Why did you mark the other one answer? He just repeated what I already said

Comment: I apologise grennis, it is because he said it in a way that made sense to me more and answered my specific quesiton